# Changing shutdown sound effect in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04

How can I change the shutdown sound effect in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find system sounds in the `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/` directory. From there, you can change the .ogg files with your own.